# Tensorflow No gradients provided for any variable with different shape of variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    images, labels = x
    initial_points = self.model(images, is_training=True)
    final_images = (tf.ones_like(initial_points) + initial_points).numpy()
    final_images = np.expand_dims(final_images, axis=-1)
    final_labels = tf.zeros_like(final_images)
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=final_images, labels=final_labels)
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
```

Why is it that if I modify the shape of the model output using np.expand_dims(), I get the following error:

"ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable ... " when applying the gradients to my model variables? It works fine if I don't have the np.expand_dims() though. Is it because the model loss has to have the same shape as the model output? Or is it non-differentiable?

Answer (score 2):

Always, use `TensorFlow` version of `NumPy` functions, to avoid this kind of error.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    images, labels = x
    initial_points = self.model(images, is_training=True)
    final_images = (tf.ones_like(initial_points) + initial_points).numpy()
    final_images = tf.expand_dims(final_images, axis=-1)
    final_labels = tf.zeros_like(final_images)
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=final_images, labels=final_labels)
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
```

Answer (score 1):

The TensorFlow library operates in a very specific matter when you are using `tf.GradientTape()`. Under this function, it is automatically computing partial derivatives for you in order to update the gradients afterwards. It can do this because each `tf` function was designed for this specifically.

When you use a `NumPy` function, however, there is a break in the formula. TensorFlow does not know/understand this function, and thus cannot compute the partial derivative of your loss via the chain rule anymore.

You must use only `tf` functions under `GradientTape()` for this reason.